# ¿Cómo quitar acentos y Caracteres especiales en Java?

Tags: java, regex

Tengo una cadena de texto, la cual no quiere que tenga tildes ni caracteres especiales.

He leído respecto a la propiedad `replaceAll` y el `Pattern` en Java y el uso de Expresiones regulares, el problema es que es un tema nuevo para mi y no logro implementarlo.

**En teoría:** Si mis caracteres son *"áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚäÄëËïÏöÖüÜñÑ"* debiera quedar *"aAeEiIoOuUaAeEiIoOuUnÑ"* y no aceptar caracteres especiales.

**regex 1:** [!"#$%&'()*+,
-./:;<=>?@[
\]^_‘{|}~]

**regex 2** áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚäÄëËïÏöÖüÜñÑ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) de Java.

Se podría poner en una función:

**<kbd>[VER DEMO](https://rextester.com/QNXEW99772)</kbd>**

```
public static String stripAccents(String s) 
{
    /*Salvamos las ñ*/
    s = s.replace('ñ', '\001');
    s = s.replace('Ñ', '\002');
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");
    /*Volvemos las ñ a la cadena*/
    s = s.replace('\001', 'ñ');
    s = s.replace('\002', 'Ñ');

    return s;
}
```

**Prueba:**

```
System.out.println(stripAccents("áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚäÄëËïÏöÖüÜñÑ"));
```

**Salida:**

```
aAeEiIoOuUaAeEiIoOuUñÑ
```

### Explicación del código

- `s` es la cadena a reemplazar, recibida en parámetro
- se reemplaza a `ñ` y a `Ñ` por dos caracteres no imprimibles, para preservarlas, porque de lo contrario las cambiaría por `n` o por `N`
- `NFD` hace referencia a la forma de normalización descritas en el [estándar Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html). La clase `Normalizer` admite [cuatro](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html), y `NFD` es una de ellas, significa forma de *descomposición canónica*.
- `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` es una [propiedad de los caracteres Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Properties) que permite referirse a un bloque de caracteres agrupados por ciertos criterios. Este en concreto se refiere a los acentos diacríticos. Cabe destacar que si no se va a trabajar con caracteres Unicode esta expresión quizá tenga que ser cambiada por una expresión regular adecuada al tipo de codificación con el que se vaya a trabajar (para más detalles puedes [consultar aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697575/5587982)).
- Las dos líneas que siguen son para restableces las `ñ` o `Ñ` que salvamos anteriormente
- Y finalmente retornamos a `s` que será la cadena con los reemplazos hechos.

<s>Aquí `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks` sirve para extraer absolutamente todos los acentos diacríticos, incluido el de la `ñ`. Dado que conozco muy poco de REGEX, se podría implementar una expresión regular que haga el trabajo de `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks` exceptuando `ñ` y `Ñ`. Dado que REGEX no es muy fuerte, lo he hecho con truco.</s>

---

### Fuentes:

1. [Easy way to remove accents from a Unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15190656/5587982)
2. [Normalize a string except ñ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36098063/5587982)

Comment: Dos preguntas, porque desconozco la función de los objetos Normalizer. En la propiedad `nomalize` el parámetro s y Normalizer.Form.NFD que es lo que hacen.

Comment: La segunda es en el `replaceAll` que función tiene el espacio en blanco y el otro parámetro s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");

Comment: @FernyCortez mira si ahora queda más claro.

Comment: las comillas "" vacias en el `replaceAll`, ¿Qué indican?

Comment: @FernyCortez lo que ocurre en esta línea: `s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "")` es que se aplica la propiedad `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks`, propia de Unicode, que elimina todos los acentos diacríticos que haya en `s`. No se pone nada como reemplazo porque precisamente esa propiedad lo que hace es quitar los diacríticos  [Ver aquí](https://loquemeinteresadelared.wordpress.com/tag/incombiningdiacriticalmarks/), para más detalles.

Comment: Esa era mi duda, pensé que los eliminaba, solamente quita los acentos, según entiendo

Comment: @FernyCortez sí, lo que hace es, por decirlo de alguna manera, *limpiar los caracteres de acentos diacríticos*. Si en la prueba tú pones algo de reemplazo, verás que quita los acentos y agrega lo que le pongas entre comillas.

Comment: @FernyCortez quizá algún experto en REGEX podría lograr una expresión que tome  `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks` pero ignorando el acento de la `Ñ`.

Comment: De hecho, es uno de los muchos problemas que me he topado, entre ellos tengo generar caracteres aleatorios alfanuméricos. Hay forma de etiquetar personas, que nos han ayudado, para consultarles en stackoverflow?

Comment: Ferny la forma es mencionándolos en comentarios. Alguien muy bueno en REGEX es @Mariano pero hace tiempo que no lo veo por aquí.

Comment: Leeré mas al respecto